# regex matching negation to ebay sites

Tags: java, regex

I have a regex to match any ebay sites:

```
(?i)^((http|https)://)?(\w+\.)*ebay.(\w+.)+
```

I want to negate it, to match all, except this sites

I tried:

```
(?! pattern )
(?!pattern)
[^pattern]
```

But nothing worked. Maybe my first regex is too unoptimal?

Testcase in java:

```
Pattern queryPattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)^((http|https)://)?(\\w+\\.)*ebay.(\\w+.)+");
List<String> queries = new LinkedList();
queries.add("http://www.ebay.com/blabla");
queries.add("www.ebay.com/blabla");
queries.add("www.eBay.com/blabla");
queries.add("www.ebay.com.hk/blabla");
queries.add("www.ebay.co.uk");
queries.add("ttt.ebay.com");
queries.add("ru.ebay.com");
queries.add("test.ru.ebay.com");
queries.add("test.ru.ebAY.com");
queries.add("ebay.com");
queries.add("naebay.com");
queries.add("ru.naebay.ru");
queries.add("blah.ru");
for (String query : queries) {
  System.out.println(query + " " + queryPattern.matcher(query).find());
}
```

Comment: `!queryPattern.matcher(query).find()` should suit your needs `:)`

Comment: sp00m, i don't want add aditional params to project code, testcase just testcase :)

Answer (score 6):

Obvious response:

```
    Pattern queryPattern = Pattern.compile("(?i)^((http|https)://)?(\\w+\\.)*ebay.(\\w+.)+");
    List<String> queries = new LinkedList<String>();
    ...

    for (String query : queries) {
        if (queryPattern.matcher(query).find() == false) {
            System.out.println("Non Ebay site: " + query + " " + queryPattern.matcher(query).find());
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
Non Ebay site: naebay.com false
Non Ebay site: ru.naebay.ru false
Non Ebay site: blah.ru false
```

Answer (score 2):

Avoid regex to parse irregular patterns like url,html.Use URL class.

To solve your problem You can use `(?!.*ebay)` at the start of your pattern i.e after `^`

---

Instead of parsing with regex you could use [URL](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html) class like this

```
URL url = new URL(yourURL);
if(!url.getHost().contains("ebay")){}
```